# Can I play catan-seafarers 5-6 player extension without the actual seafarers?

Tags: catan, catan-seafarers

I have just bought the 5-6 player seafarers extension for catan and I also have the basic catan.
Can I play like this? or do I have to have the normal seafarers?

Comment: Which version of the expansion do you have? All of them should say exactly what you need on the back of the box. e.g. https://boardgamegeek.com/image/43110

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need Seafarers to play the Seafarers 5-6 expansion as intended.

According to https://catanshop.com/catan-seafarers-5-6-player-extension

> NOT a complete game! You need a CATAN® game (aka The Settlers of CATAN®), a CATANⓇ: 5-6 Player extension, and a CATANⓇ: Seafarers expansion in order to play with this game extension!

Comment: He also needs the catan 5-6 player extension

Comment: @Jungkook quoted in the answer: "... a CATANⓇ: 5-6 Player extension..."

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson in the quoted text it says that. But the answer itself says 'you need Seafarers' I think it's important to state explicitly that the 5-6 extension is also required.

Comment: @Jungkook This is being pedantic.  The question was asked if the base version of Seafarers was required.  The answer is yes.  The quote covers another options.

Comment: @LeppyR64 Indeed. Making this answer perfect as-is. Well done.